# How to use Microsoft.Web.Administration without IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis

I develop my site on Windows 2003 using IIS6 and Development Server that ships with Visual Studio 2008. My production site is on IIS7.

How can I use/reference Microsoft.Web.Administration during my development without moving it to IIS7-enabled machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do this. IIS6 and IIS7 are completely different products and there are major differences in the way that configuration data is stored.

You could mock/stub the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace but I think your time would be better spent moving to an OS that runs IIS7 (Vista, Windows 7, Windows 2008).

Comment: Thought so, but asked to be sure :)